# List comprehension python and specific item

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
list_input = [(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (z,b), (z,e)]
```

I want to extract b, c and d when start it with "a" not with "z" and put in a list

I could not figure out how to do it, any advice?

Comment: That is not a list comprehension. You have a normal list; there is no `for` loop involved here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter your list items on the first value, collecting the second:

```
[second for first, second in list_input if first == 'a']
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_input = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('z', 'b'), ('z', 'e')]
>>> [second for first, second in list_input if first == 'a']
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or;

```
list_input = [("a","b"), ("a","c"), ("a","d"), ("z","b"), ("z","e")]

print ([x[1] for x in list_input if x[0]=="a"])

>>> 
['b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

Manipulate it with indices. You can display that specific pairs too;

```
print ([(x,x[1]) for x in list_input if x[0]=="a"])
```

output;

```
>>> 
[(('a', 'b'), 'b'), (('a', 'c'), 'c'), (('a', 'd'), 'd')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it explicitly:

```
In [8]: [list_input[i][1] for i in xrange(len(list_input)) if list_input[i][0] =='a']
Out[8]: ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I would suggest that of the options available, you do it @Martijn's way. It's the nicest. I just posted this to show you yet another way to do it... Bow to the power of python :P